# unix bash - extract a line from file

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, awk, grep

need your help!!! I tried looking for this but to no avail.

How can I achieve the following using bash?

I've a flat file called "cube.mdl" that contains:

```
[...]
bla bla bla bla lots of lines above
Cube 8007841 "BILA_" MdcFile "BILA_CO_PM_MKT_BR_CUBE.mdc"
bla bla bla more lines below
[...]
```

I need to open that file, look for the word "MdcFile" and get the string that follows between quotes, which would be `BILA_CO_PM_MKT_BR_CUBE.mdc`

I know AWK or grep are powerful enough to do this in one line, but I couldn't find an example that could help me do it on my own.

Thanks in advance!
JMA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -o -P "MdcFile.*" cube.mdl | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
```

This will use `grep`'s regex to only return `MdcFile` and everything after it in the current line. Then, `awk` will use the `"` as a delimiter and print only the second word - which would be your "in-quotes" word(s), returned without the quotes of course.

The option `-o`, `--only-matching` specifies to return only the text matching that matches and the `-P`, `--perl-regexp` specifies that the pattern is a Perl-Regex pattern. It appears that some versions of grep do not contain these options. The OP's version is a version that does not include them, but the following appears to work for him instead:

```
grep "MdcFile.*" cube.mdl | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Thank you man for your input, i tried it but seems this unix doesn't like something about it. I got: grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- P

Comment: thank you Dude, look i removed the -o and -P parameters and I GOT THE CORRECT OUTPUT! :D     are those -o -P parameters a MUST? Please explain.. thank you!

Comment: @jmaltube Hah; apparently, in your case, not. The `-o` specifies to return only the matching text, and the `-P` specifies to use Perl's regex engine. In my version, they're required - without them it fails. I'm running `GNU Grep 2.6.3`, if it matters - but if yours is working, your version must match on patterns like this by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep MdcFile cube.mdl | awk '{print $5}'
```

would do it, assuming there's no spaces in any of those bits to throw off the position count.

Comment: That would print the the `"`s too. And there's an unnecessary process... (`awk '/MdcFile / {print $5}'`).

Comment: Thank you very much Marc, That is true, it is including the quotes in the output.

Comment: Zsolt Botykai, how can i implement what you suggested?. Kinda combine it with what Marc posted.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.

```
sed -n '/MdcFile / s/.*MdcFile "\(\[^"\]\+\)".*/\1/;/MdcFile / p' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: It doesn't work (I tested it). First, the substitution command left a slash at the end without the first group matched (`\1`). Second, square brackets need not be escaped. Third, the print command (`p`) always executes, so lines that don't match `MdcFile` also are printed. Something like this would be more accurate: `sed -ne '/MdcFile/ { s/^.*MdcFile[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/; p; }' infile`

Comment: hey Birei, first off, thank you. Your suggestion almost worked, it extracted correctly the words "in-quotes" but it also extracted the first word of the line below. It kinda didn't recognize the break line or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` for the whole thing with `"` as record separator:

```
awk -v RS='"' '/MdcFile/ { getline; print }' cube.mdl
```